# I am trying to declare an 2d array with initialized column values but the following code gives "not a statement error"

Tags: java, arrays

what is wrong with the following declaration with initialization of an 2d array in java??

```
String[][] un=new String[n2]{"a","0","0"};
```

n2 is an initialized variable.

Comment: What do you expect the content of the array to be, given your code?

Comment: i want an array with those constant column values but wants the size of rows to be n2.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```java
String[] const_arr = {"a", "0", "0"};
String[][] un = new String[n2][const_arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < const_arr.length; j++) {
        un[i][j] = const_arr[j];
    }
}
```

**P.S.:** I don't understand the purpose of the matrix `un` as it only contains a constant array. Personally, I feel you should refactor your code to use only `const_arr` and not create this matrix.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the syntax is not correct (you cannot put the variable inside the bracket). Secondly the array initialization with both dimension expression and initialization is illegal.

The straight declaration for two-dimensional array is:

```
    String[][] un=new String[][]{{"1", "2", "3"},{"a","0","0"}};
```

To get what you want you can try something like:

```
    String[] n2 = new String[] {"1", "2", "3"};
    String[][] un = new String[][]{n2,{"a","0","0"}};
```

but if you want the array to be something like this :{[a,b,c],[a,b,c],......[a,b,c]}, i.e. number of rows should be the value of n2 variable, then:

```
    String[] n2 = new String[] {"1", "2", "3"};
    String[][] un = new String[n2.length][];
    for (int i=0; i<un.length; i++) {
        un[i] = n2;
    }
```

Comment: but i want the size of rows should be equal to the value of n2 and column values should be same for every row.

Comment: i want the array to be something like this :{[a,b,c],[a,b,c],......[a,b,c]}. no of rows should be the value of n2 variable.